# Grails webflow - converting action based to web flow

Tags: grails

Our app is working using the normal actions in the controller, but there are some difficulties in going backward from one page to another. I've been tasked with converting this to use web flows instead and I'm hitting all kinds of road blocks. Suggestions and insights greatly appreciated.

The controller has actions for list, view, create, sign and print. I've done this:

```
def index = {
    redirect (action: "someFlow")
}

def someFlow = {
    init {
        // some object settings
    }
    on("success").to("list")

    list {
    }
    on("create").to "create"
    on("view).to "view"

    create {
    }
    on("next").to "sign"
    on("cancel).to "list"

    view {
    }
    on("edit").to "create"
    on("back").to "list"

    sign {
    }
    on("done").to "list"
    on("back").to "create"

    edit {
    }
    on("done").to "view"

}
```

When I trace through this with the debugger it appears to hit every state in succession without doing anything or stopping on any page. Then it goes back to the list state.

If I click the link for 'create' I get a web page telling me the "resource (/directory path/create) is not available."

But if it could find the list.gsp, why can't it find the create.gsp?

I feel like I'm groping blindly in the dark; none of the books seems to address any of this and I can't find any other resources to indicate why it behaves this way. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: For the sake of more information, can you give us a directory listing for `your_application/grails-app/views/someFlow/`?

Comment: Also, perhaps I'm missing something, but the actions you've laid out don't really seem like they're good candidates for a WebFlow. Are these just the standard (scaffolded) Grails controller actions? If so, I don't think using a WebFlow is the best idea for navigating between them. Perhaps you can comment on what your "difficulties in going backward from one page to another" are. There's probably a better solution.

Comment: Also, one final comment - you're missing a `"` in your `list` state's `on("view).to "view"` - is that missing in your actual code, too?

Answer (score 0):

The "on" statements need to be inside of the closures.  For example, this:

```
list {
}
on("create").to "create"
on("view").to "view"
```

should be this:

```
list {
    on("create").to "create"
    on("view").to "view"
}
```

That should at least fix the issue with flying through the whole flow.  As for the GSPs not being found, you'll need to create a folder (named "some") in the folder for your controller.  Place the GSPs for each of the actions in your flow inside here.

That being said, I agree with Rob that it doesn't really seem like a good candidate for a webflow.

Comment: So, the directory structure looks like this: my_application/grails-app/views/someFlow/ for the .gsp files. The controller, of course, is a level up in the Controllers directory. Standard grails setup really. As to whether this is really the best candidate for webflows, it's not really up to me. This is what I've been tasked with.

Comment: Also, my apologies on the example. I do have the on("view") in full quotes, and yes, the 'on' statements are inside the braces.